# Another asymmetric inequality $5+\frac{3(a^2+2b^2+c^2)}{(a+b)(b+c)} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, muirhead-inequality

A while ago I conjectured [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519062/asymmetric-inequality-in-three-variables-frac3ab2bc24ab2c-geq-7) inequality and its (little) [sister](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u519533h1990680p13874926) on AOPS. Here is another related inequality in the opposite direction which I strongly suspect is true, although I don't have a proof:

> Consider three positive real numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$. Prove (or disprove) that the following inequality holds:
>
> $$5+\frac{3(a^2+2b^2+c^2)}{(a+b)(b+c)} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$$

The idea of reducing to a symmetric inequality does not work, that is:

$$\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)}{(a+b)(b+c)} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$$

and trying to prove

$$\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)}{a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$$

does not work because this inequality is false at $c = 0$, but the proposed inequality is true at $c = 0$.

How can we prove this inequality?

Comment: homogeneous degree zero, you might as well restrict $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1.$ You didn't make complete symmetry, but you will  likely get some use from partial switch to $u=a+b+c,$   $v = ab +bc+ca,$  $w=abc$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $$\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)}{a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)-8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$$
is true!

It's just $$\sum_{cyc}(2a^4b+2a^4c-2a^3b^2-2a^3c^2+7a^3bc-7a^2b^2c)\geq0,$$ which is true by Muirhead.

Comment: You are right. But something strange is happening. Initially, I proved $1+\frac{(a^2+2b^2+c^2)}{(a+b)(b+c)} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{4(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$, which is weaker than the one I proposed above. However, this idea certainly does not work for this one, because I arrive at $\sum_{cyc} (a^4b+ab^4-2a^2b^3-2a^3b^2+6a^3bc-4a^2b^2c) \geq 0$ and this is not true for $c=0$. I automatically (and wrongly) assumed this happens for the inequality I proposed above as well. Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: @Atticus I think, you made a mistake. Your second inequality is also true. It's equivalent to $\sum\limits_{sym}(3a^4b-2a^3b^2+4a^3bc-5a^2b^2c)\geq0,$ which is obvious.

Comment: You are right again. My blunder. I was wrongly simplifying a $2$ and trying to prove $1+\frac{(a^2+2b^2+c^2)}{(a+b)(b+c)} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{2(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$ which cannot hold. For $1+\frac{(a^2+2b^2+c^2)}{(a+b)(b+c)} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{4(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$, correct it is to arrive at $\sum_{cyc} (3a^4b+3ab^4-2a^3b^2-2a^2b^3+8a^3bc-10a^2b^2c)\geq 0$, which is obvious.

Comment: @Mr Rozenberg, I found for the inequality $(2-k)+k\cdot \frac{a^2+2b^2+c^2}{(a+b)(b+c)} \geq \frac{9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{4(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)}$ that $k=\frac{3}{4}$ (the proposed problem) is the best value we can prove by symmetric inequality. However, the best value of $k$ for which it holds, is $\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{12}$. For this value of $k$, we have two equality cases $a=b=c$ and $b=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}-1},\ c=0$. Do you agree?

Comment: @Atticus I need to think about it...